# ansible Task separation via Variables must be stored as a dictionary/hash

Tags: ansible

```
- name: gather os specific variables
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version}}.yml"
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
  tags: vars
```

Trying to setup a multi linux distros ansible playbook i did used the suggested playbook from the official ansible doc
https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/os-dependent-tasks/variables/

i did added Centos-6.yml and Debian-9.yml for tests but the result is the following

> failed: [1.1.1.1]
> (item=/home/ansible/ansible-scripts/2AllInOne/CentOS-6.yml) => {
> "ansible_facts": {},
> "ansible_included_var_files": [],
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "item": "/home/ansible/ansible-scripts/2AllInOne/CentOS-6.yml",
> "message": "/home/ansible/ansible-scripts/2AllInOne/CentOS-6.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"

Any suggestion what the issue can be?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *CentOS-6.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash. What the issue can be?*

A: The issue is the format of the file `CentOS-6.yml`. It must be a [valid YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/) and must contain `dictionary/hash` aka [mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//). For example

```yaml
shell> cat CentOS-6.yml
my_dictionary:
  my_distro: Centos
  my_major: 6
  my_file: CentOS-6.yml
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, i did added it but when i do add command it does display issues:
"We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML"
```my_dictionary:
  my_distro: Centos
  my_major: 6
  my_file: CentOS-6.yml

  - name: install the latest version of Htop
    yum:
      name: htop
      state: latest```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue after modifying the yml as below:

```yaml
1 ---  
2 - User_pass: varfileinclude
```

to

```yaml
1 ---

2 User_pass: varfileinclude

# removed "-" from the variable.
```

Comment: That’s a critical change indeed. Maybe worthwhile to add that the leading dash `-` makes an entry part of a vector, while removing it creates a dict entry.